# How the following two definitions of faithful action are equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

There is two definition of faithful action:

> **Definition 1:** By a faithful action of a topological group $G$ on a topological manifold $M$, we
>   mean a continuous injection $G \to \rm{Homeo}(M)$ (where $\rm{Homeo}(M)$ has the compact-open topology).
>
> **Definition 2:** The action of $G$ on $M$ is called Faithful (or effective) if for every two distinct $g, h$ in $G$ there exists an $p\in M$ such that $g⋅p \neq h⋅p$.

How  this two definitions of faithful action are related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 implies thas 2.
 if $f:G\rightarrow Homeo(M)$ is injective, for every $g\in G, f(g)\neq Id_M$ it implies that there exists $x,y\in M$ such that $f(g).x\neq f(g).y$

2 implies 1.
Let $g\in G$ distinct of the identity, there exists $x,y\in M$ such that $f(g).x\neq f(g).y$ this implies that $f(g)\neq Id_M and $f$ is injective.

You can also say:
2. is equivalent to says that for every $g,h$ distinct, there exists $p\in M$ such that $f(g).p\neq f(h).p$ i.e $f(h^{-1}g).p\neq p$ i.e $f(h^{-1})g\neq Id_M$ and this means $f(g)\neq f(h)$.